# Puppet fails to mount a CIFS share

Tags: puppet

I have a Puppet module that I use to mount a CIFS share. 
Both the puppetmaster and the agents are running SLES 11.

The mount works manually with this command:

```
mount.cifs //servername/path/to/share /opt/some/dir -o auto,credentials=/root/.smbcred
```

But when puppet tries to mount it, it fails:

```
hostname:~ # puppet agent --test --verbose
notice: /Stage[main]/module_name/Mount[/opt/some/dir]/ensure: defined 'ensure' as 'mounted'
err: /Stage[main]/module_name/Mount[/opt/some/dir]: Could not evaluate: Field 'device' is required
```

Here's the relevant section of the init.pp for the module:

```
file { "/opt/some/dir":
    ensure => directory,
}

file { "/root/.smbcred":
    owner   => root,
    group   => root,
    mode    => 0644,
    ensure  => present,
    content =>  "user=username\npass=password\ndomain=$domain\n",
}

mount {"/opt/some/dir":
    device => "//servername/path/to/share",
    name => "/opt/some/dir",
    atboot => "true",
    ensure => "mounted",
    fstype => "cifs",
    options => "auto,credentials=/root/.smbcred",
    require => [ File["/root/.smbcred"], File["/opt/some/dir"] ],
}
```

The credentials file does get written and the directory does get created.  But the mount just fails.  Any ideas?

Comment: The style guide suggests quoting variables in donne quoted strings like "#{this}".  FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name field is redundant

Does the mount work after the credentials file gets written and the dir created?

run it with --debug

are there errors in /etc/fstab ?

Comment: Yep.  It was an error in the /etc/fstab file.  I removed the offending line and puppet works fine.  Now I have to figure out what put the bad line into the fstab.  The hunt continues.